# Using enums as a generic type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to achieve some functionality that looks like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
   ONE = "ONE", 
   TWO = "TWO"
}

interface MyInterface<T extends enum> { //Obviously wrong syntax
    value: T; //Use a single value of the enum
    values: Record<T, number>; //Use all of the keys of the enum
    optionalValues: Record<T?, number>; //Use only the keys of the enum, but not necessarily all of them. 
}


const a : MyInterface<MyEnum>  = {
    value: "ONE",  //OK
    values: {
       ONE: 1,    //OK
       TWO: 2, 
       THREE: 3 //NOT OK 
    }, 
    optionalValues: {
       ONE: 111,   //OK
       THREE: 3    //NOT OK 
    }
}

const b : MyInterface<MyEnum>  = {
    value: MyEnum.ONE,  //OK
    values: {
       ONE: 1,    //Not ok - not all enum values used
    }, 
    optionalValues: {
       [MyEnum.ONE]: 111,   //Ok, and generally this is the way I want to be using this. 
    }
}
```

That is - I want to be able to use enums as a way to specify a list of keys, and then define interfaces as objects that contain those keys.

ie.

```
const iceCreams = MyInterface<IceCreamFlavours> = {
   ...
}

const fruit = MyInterface<FruitTypes> = {
    ...
}
```

How can I achieve this? It seems like a fairly common use case.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you just define the interfaces, doesn't `keyof` provide the functionality of the enums?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not getting it at all. Hopefully someone else does.

Comment: It's unclear to me, do you want to use `[MyEnum.ONE]` or `"ONE"` as keys? Either is possible but you can't mix them if you want to ensure all members are specified. Also there is no `enum` constraint, best we can do is constarin to an object with `number` or `string` values, I can provide a reference for that if you want (i know there is a GH issue I just have to search for it)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Ideally I could use "ONE", although it wouldn't pain me if I had to use square brackets. Is this the github issue? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13042

Comment: @dwjohnston this was the one I had in mind https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30611

Comment: @dwjohnston I'll provide a solution when I have a break (eta 20-30 mins) if anyone else doesn't get to it by then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `enum` constraint. Enums can be either `string` or `number`, so a constraint of `string | number` is the best we can do:

```
interface MyInterface<T extends string | number> {
    value: T; //Use a single value of the enum
    values: Record<T, number>; //Use all of the keys of the enum
    optionalValues: Partial<Record<T, number>>; //Use only the keys of the enum, but not necessarily all of them. 
}

enum MyEnum {
   ONE = "ONE", 
   TWO = "TWO"
}

const a : MyInterface<MyEnum>  = {
    value: MyEnum.ONE,  //OK
    values: {
       [MyEnum.ONE]: 1,    //OK
       [MyEnum.TWO]: 2, 
       [MyEnum.THREE]: 3 //NOT OK 
    }, 
    optionalValues: {
       [MyEnum.ONE]: 111,   //OK
       [MyEnum.THREE]: 3    //NOT OK 
    }
}
```

We can also use the enum member names but then we have to pass in the type for enum container object not the the type of the enum.

```
interface MyInterface<T extends Record<keyof T, string | number>> { // enum like object 
    value: keyof T; //Use a single value of the enum
    values: Record<keyof T, number>; //Use all of the keys of the enum
    optionalValues: Partial<Record<keyof T, number>>; //Use only the keys of the enum, but not necessarily all of them. 
}

enum MyEnum {
ONE = "ONE", 
TWO = "TWO"
}

const a : MyInterface<typeof MyEnum>  = {
    value: "ONE",  //OK
    values: {
    "ONE": 1,    //OK
    "TWO": 2, 
    "THREE": 3 //NOT OK 
    }, 
    optionalValues: {
    "ONE": 111,   //OK
    "THREE": 3    //NOT OK 
    }
}
```